# Как убрать дублирование кода? Firebase SearchQuery android

Tags: android, запрос, firebase, firebase-database

Метод который делает запрос

```
public void ShowData(Query postsQuery) {

    mActivity = getActivity();
    final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mActivity, R.style.NewDialog);
    mDialog.addContentView(
            new ProgressBar(mActivity),
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    );
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.show();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(postsQuery, Post.class)
            .build();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, int position, final Post model) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

            // Determine if the current user has liked this post and set UI accordingly
            if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
            } else {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(model.kzSongytblink))
                viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_line_logo);
            else viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.off_line_logo);

            // Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
            viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View starView) {
                    // Need to write to both places the post is stored
                    DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("songsDB").child(postRef.getKey());
                    // Run two transactions
                    onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, PostDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PostDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postRef.getKey());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            return new PostViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

А это метод который делает запрос по поиску

```
public void SearchData(String searchText){
    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("songsDB").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    mActivity = getActivity();
    final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mActivity, R.style.NewDialog);
    mDialog.addContentView(
            new ProgressBar(mActivity),
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    );
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.show();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, Post.class)
            .build();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, int position, final Post model) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

            // Determine if the current user has liked this post and set UI accordingly
            if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
            } else {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(model.kzSongytblink))
                viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_line_logo);
            else viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.off_line_logo);

            // Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
            viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View starView) {
                    // Need to write to both places the post is stored
                    DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("songsDB").child(postRef.getKey());
                    // Run two transactions
                    onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, PostDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PostDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postRef.getKey());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            return new PostViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Хочу убрать это дублирование , делал много чего но метод Search все время ломался?Помогите пожалуйста..

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    //inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it present
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            SearchData(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Filter as you type
            SearchData(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Вы пробовали в методе `SearchData` вызывать `ShowData(firebaseSearchQuery)`?

Comment: пробовал ,у меня перестает работает SearchData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, только я не знаю где у тебя инициализируется `mActivity`

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter getMAdapter(Query query){

mActivity = getActivity();
final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mActivity, R.style.NewDialog);
mDialog.addContentView(
        new ProgressBar(mActivity),
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
);
mDialog.setCancelable(true);
mDialog.show();

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
        .setQuery(query, Post.class)
        .build();

mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, int position, final Post model) {
        final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

        // Determine if the current user has liked this post and set UI accordingly
        if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
            viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
        } else {
            viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(model.kzSongytblink))
            viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_line_logo);
        else viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.off_line_logo);

        // Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
        viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View starView) {
                // Need to write to both places the post is stored
                DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("songsDB").child(postRef.getKey());
                // Run two transactions
                onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
            }
        });

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, PostDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PostDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postRef.getKey());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        return new PostViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        super.onDataChanged();
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
return mAdapter;
}


public void ShowData(Query postsQuery) {

mAdapter=getMAdapter(postsQuery);
mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

public void SearchData(String searchText){
Query postsQuery= mDatabase.orderByChild("songsDB").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

mAdapter=getMAdapter(postsQuery);
mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: setMadapter ничего возвращать не должен?

Comment: @ЖанболатМаратов, верно.Спасибо. В текстовике сложно сравнивать (

Comment: Все отлично , вот только теперь не могу найти проблему почему поисковик не работает)

Comment: как именно он не работает? ошибка или что-то еще?

Comment: печатаю 0 реакции

Comment: щас я добавлю  oncreateoptions , можешь взглянуть

Comment: вроде бы все верно

Comment: @ЖанболатМаратов, я с андроидом далек) Что в итоге должно произойти, если всегда возвращается false? и почему у вас `onQueryTextSubmit` и `onQueryTextChange`  вызывают `SearchData` ? Так и должно быть? или 1 должен поккзывать, а второй искать?

Comment: Первый когда первый раз вводишь , а второй когда ты его изменяешь на другой запрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92242/discussion-between-dred-and--).

Comment: Заработал, ошибка была в том что я не прописал в         
onCreateView setHasOptionsMenu(true);

Comment: @ЖанболатМаратов Мы даже не видели эту строчку

Comment: ну это мой косяк,